# if $\phi$ is a linear trasformation on V, its matrix under a group of base vectors is a jordan block, is this V is a cyclic space under $\phi$?

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

I only know if jordan block is $J_n(0)$ then V will be cyclic space under corresponding linear transformation $\phi$. Will this right for any $J_n(a)\ (a\neq 0)$?

I was really confused while discussing this with my friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint*. $J_n(\lambda)-\lambda I=J_n(0)$.

> If a linear operator $A$ acting on a vector space $V$ of dimension $n$ is equivalent to a single Jordan block $J_n(\lambda)$, without loss of generality $V=\mathbb{C}^n$ and $A=J_n(\lambda)$. Then $(A-\lambda I)^ke_n=e_{n-k}$ so $e_n$ is a cyclic generator.

Comment: So $V$ is a cyclic space under $(A-\lambda I)^k$ instead of $A$ ?

Comment: @P.Scotty That's not what I'm saying. You can expand $(A-\lambda I)^k$ and the result is a linear combination of powers of $A$. Remember $v$ cyclically generates $V$ with respect to $A$ if $v,Av,A^2v,\cdots$ spans $V$.